# Reading output from "line-driver" hall-effect sensor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

I am trying to control a 3 phase brushless dc motor with integrated hall-effect sensors.  I understand how to do this with your typical open-collector hall effects, however according to the manufacturer these are "line-driver" hall effect sensors.  I do not understand how to read them.

Instead of just having 1 output for each halleffect this motor appears to have 2.  I have hooked 12v to Vcc and Ground to ground and measured the output of both the + and - output of the halleffects.  There seems to be 3 possible outputs at each output ~6.86, ~5.8, ~ 5.  I have to be missing something right??

I have attached the very limited information the manufacturer has given me[image: pinout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "raw" Hall effect sensor will give an output voltage proportional to the current and orthagonal magnetic field.

[image]

*Figure 1. The principle of the Hall effect. Source: Wikipedia [Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect).*

- In your case it seems as though you have two output terminals per sensor. These would correspond to \$ V_H+ \$ and \$ V_H- \$ in Figure 1.
- Since the Hall effect produces quite low voltages it seems reasonable to assume that some amplification of the signal takes place in the chip.
- Since the chip has single rail supply it also makes sense that the voltage would vary around mid-supply. This is 5.8 V in your case.
- It also seems plausible that there are three possible states for the sensor:

  - North pole at sensor.
  - Neither or balanced / cancelling / opposing poles at sensor.
  - South pole at sensor.
- These three options would explain your three output voltages. More than likely you should find that when A+ is high that A- is low and vice versa. You should also find that when A+ is neutral that A- is too.

To "decode" these signals you will need three analog comparators.

[image]

*Figure 2. The only similar circuit found on a web search shows the three sensors in series rather than parallel. This is an efficient approach where possible as the series current reduces overall current consumption. The [TLC3704](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc3704.pdf) contains four comparitors. Image source: [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/anachrocomputer/3234878301).*

Comment: Ok, what you are saying makes perfect sense.  However I have a concern with simply using a comparator to decode the signal.  When A+ and A- are both neutral I can still have 35mv of differential voltage between them....  Is there a way to account for this?

Comment: Hysteresis on the comparitor is what you need. Since you've got about 1 V low to high I'd be looking for about 0.25 V hysteresis. You'll have to figure out how to do that with the comparator you choose. Generally you add a little positive feedback. Plenty on the web on the subject.